# how to figure image size to fit below header and above footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, resize

I want to center an image in the available space below the page header and above the page footer.
It needs to be responsive, so I want the picture to be as large as possible but not overlap the header and footer.

The ID of the image is #nMapImg.

I have these values:

```
var dh=$(document).height();
var dw=$(document).width();
var hh=$("#header").height();
var fh=$("#footer").height();
var w=$("#nMapImg").width();
var availHeight=h-hh-fh;
```

I think this is just math to figure the max size I can have and then I'll center it. I just can't wrap my head around it.

[image]

Comment: Is it allowed to have a div between the header and footer which fills the height?

Comment: Yes....I think I see where you're going.

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you can achieve this with pure css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body, .app {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background: red;
}
footer {
  background: blue;
}
footer, header {
  height: 400px; 
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="" />
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said it is allowed to place a div between the header and footer the easiest way to have the largest image possible is:

```
<div style="background-image: url('myimage.jpg'); background-size: contain"></div>
```

You can also add `background-position: center center;` when needed

Answer (score 0):

Using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and setting a height on a div where the image lies

```css
*{margin: 0;}
header{
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

footer{
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.main{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
<div class="main">
<img src="https://placehold.it//900x500" alt="" />
</div>
<footer>
  <h1>FOOTER</h1>
</footer>
```